# can make module name uppercase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**lib/modules/job/web.rb**

```
module Modules
  module JOB
    class Web
      def self.type
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I used - `Modules::JOB::Web.type`

but I am getting this error -

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Modules::JOB 
Did you mean?  Modules::Job
```

Is there any way to use `Modules::JOB` ?

Comment: Uppercase names are meant to be constants.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, I see. So it is not possible?

Comment: You are fighting Ruby, never a good idea.

Comment: @SebastianPalma But `Modules` is also a constant here, as is `String` for that matter. Names that *begin* with uppercase are constant (e.g. `Co = 11; defined? Co` says `"constant"`).

Comment: That's more precise @muistooshort. Totally right.

Comment: I'm guessing that your problem is with the Rails loader rather than Ruby itself. If you dump that `Modules::JOB::Web` definition into `irb`, it works fine. Maybe Rails is getting confused by the `JOB` and not knowing which file to autoload. Maybe you could manually `require 'modules/job/web'` or update the autoload paths but you'd probably be better off following the conventions.

Comment: Using all-uppercase constants for modules or classes is perfectly fine. Popular examples from within Ruby itself are `CSV`, `IO`, `JSON`, or `URI`. The issue is due to Rails' naming conventions, see [Customizing Inflections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Rails you can use `inflect.acronym` to setup special inflection rules for acronyms like IPAdress or HTTPClient which don't follow the normal camelcase convention.

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'JOB'
end
```

But this is a pretty bad idea to begin with. *job* is not an acronym and its just a blatant violation of the principle of least surprise as well as [the holy Ruby naming conventions](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes).

Having a module named "Modules" is also just silly. Organize your code around meaningful names that convey its actual purpose.

What does `Modules::JOB::Web` do? (retorical question)

Comment: I agree, specially as regards having the Modules 'namespace'. A `Job::Web module` would be just as meaningful, and also less nested.

Comment: _"job is not an acronym"_ – https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/job

Comment: @Stefan job still isn't an acronym. It's a noun. JOB is an acronym but I doubt the OP is creating a module named after the Japanese Organazion of Bodyboarding...

Comment: @max you interpreted it that way, the question just says `JOB`.

Comment: He's asked about 10 questions previously which make it pretty clear that it's a ActiveJob that we are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Rails.

You're basically hitting a wall with Rails' autoload feature: it expects lib/modules/job/web.rb to declare a Modules::Job::Web constant (remember that, in ruby, classes and modules are assigned to constants).

In my ruby/rails version, it autoloads the constant (that is, your module) successfully.
You could try to upgrade your rails/ruby or require the file manually:

```
require './lib/modules/job/web.rb'

Modules::JOB::Web.respond_to? :type # => true
```

Comment: Its actually a lot more surprising that ever it worked on your system without setting up an inflection. It does not work on Ruby 2.6.3p62 / Rails 6 with Zeitwork. And thats even on OS-X  with a case-insentive FS.

Comment: It's true, my rails version probably has different inflection rules. I was surprised myself when I copy/pasted the code in a rails project and the autoload worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended, however, since the `JOB` is effectively an acronym in this context while it's not actually. You may just comply with the file-to-constant naming convention and rename the `job.rb` file to `j_o_b.rb`.